# Removing items from a list when a condition is met

Tags: c#, .net, list, class, foreach

I'm writing a multi-threaded download manager where download info is managed by a class I wrote (called DownloadOperation). Downloads are held in a list (called download). I need to remove the objects from the list when a function in the class (queryCompleted) returns true but found out that elements could not be removed from lists from within a `foreach` loop. What is the best way to have the same effect? I'm relatively new to C# so pardon my stupidity.

```
private void removeInactiveDownloads()
    {
        foreach (DownloadOperation dl in download)
        {
            if (dl.queryComplete() == true)
            {
                // if download is no longer in progress it is removed from the list.
                download.Remove(dl);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 16):

`List<T>` has a method

```
public int RemoveAll(
    Predicate<T> match
)
```

that removes all elements matching a predicate: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx

Therefore I suggest something like:

```
download.RemoveAll(x => x.queryComplete());
```

(note that `== true` is not needed since `.queryComplete()` already returns true or false!)

Answer (score 3):

Iterate backwards in a For loop instead of a Foreach loop

```
for(int i = download.Count; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (download[i].queryComplete())
    {
       // if download is no longer in progress it is removed from the list.
       download.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome :) (although Patashu's LINQ query is much more concise)

Comment: +1 The key here being that you're not using an `IEnumerator` object.

Answer (score 1):

Patashu's answer is the best solution in general, but based on your example code I would suggest taking another approach altogether.

Are you polling the download list periodically to find the completed ones? Event subscription would probably be a better solution. Since you're new to C#, in case you didn't know the language has built-in support for this pattern: [Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx)

A download could raise a `Completed` event when it completes, which is subscribed to by the code which manages the list, something like:

```
private void AddDownload(DownloadOperation dl) {
    download.Add(dl);
    dl.Completed += (s, e) => download.Remove(dl);
}
```